# difference between two way of converting JSON byteArray

Tags: hashmap, android-bitmap

I have json image response like this:

```
"UserImage":[
255,
216,
255,
224,
0,.....]
```

there is two way that I make this response to byte array:

1 -

```
        JSONArray resultImage = result.getJSONArray("UserImage");
        byte[] byteUserImage = resultImage.toString().getBytes();
        hashUserImageMap.put(userId, byteUserImage);
```

2-

```
            byte[] tmp=new byte[result.getJSONArray("UserImage").length()];
        for(int i=0;i<result.getJSONArray("UserImage").length();i++){
            tmp[i]=(byte)(((int)result.getJSONArray("UserImage").get(i)) & 0xFF);
        }
        hashUserImageMap.put(userId, tmp);
```

in second way I could convert byteArray to bitmap:

```
byte[] arr = getMapInstance().get(name);                 
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arr, 0, arr.length);
```

but in first way this bitmap was null.
I want to know where is deference between these tow way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method calls `resultImage.toString.getBytes`. This will create a JSON string and then give you the ASCII values for each of the characters contained in there.

For `"[42]"` you will get these bytes: `[0x5B, 0x34, 0x32, 0x5D]`. They are all wrong and there are too many of them. Your `BitmapFactory` will reject it.

The second method goes through the array element by element, treats the number found there as a byte value and constructs a new array of those value.

For `"[42]"` you will get `[0x2A]` (which is what you want).